# Deserialize with Jackson with reference to an existing object

Tags: java, json, jackson

JSON

```
{
  "schools": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "School A"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "School B"
    }
  ],
  "students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bobby",
      "school": 1
    }
  ]

}
```

How would I map the JSON into the following classes such that Bobby's school is mapped to the already instantiated School A.

```
public class School {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
}

public class Student {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private School school;
}
```

I've tried some weird stuff with the Student class...

```
public class Student {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private School school;

  @JsonProperty("school")
  public void setSchool(Integer sid) {
    for (School school : getSchools()) {
      if (school.id == sid) {
        this.school = school;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that both the schools and the students are being parsed from the JSON at the same time, so I'm not sure how to get a list of the schools. Maybe I should parse these separately so I have the list of schools first?

Comment: Have you tried something? It's not clear what you're stuck on.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've tried to better explain the issue I'm trying to solve with an example of one of the approaches I've been trying to take.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jackson will do it for you. Just annotate your objects with `@JsonIdentityInfo`:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=School.class, generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class School {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public School() {
    }

    public School(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=Student.class, generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Student {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private School school;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Integer id, String name, School school) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.school = school;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public School getSchool() {
        return school;
    }

    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    School school = new School(1, "St Magdalene's");
    Student mary = new Student(1, "Mary", school);
    Student bob = new Student(2, "Bob", school);
    Student[] students = new Student[] {mary, bob};

    // Write out
    String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(students);
    System.out.println("Serialized: " + serialized);
    // Read in
    Student[] deserialized = mapper.readValue(serialized, Student[].class);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Serialized it looks like:
`[{"id":1,"name":"Mary","school":{"id":1,"name":"St Magdalene's"}},{"id":2,"name":"Bob","school":1}]`
Deserialized it doesn't link to the school object but rather stored only the id of the school.

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked the result. Without type info the deserialization was to a list of hash sets. I've updated the example to use a Student[] so that Jackson has enough info to build the objects.

Comment: As an alternative, you can let Jackson manage the ids. Remove the `id` properties and use `generator= ObjectIdGenerators .IntSequenceGenerator`.

Comment: I had deserialization issue (`JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing`) when using the default property `@id`, so I had to use another one. Note that the property name defined in the `@JsonIdentityInfo` is not required to exist in the Java object (you can define any name, e.g. `myJacksonId`). In the end I used `@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=School.class, generator= ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "myJacksonId")` only on the `School` class (it's not required on the `Student` class).

Answer (score 3):

With classes defined as below:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(property = "id", generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
class School {
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
}

class Student {
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    public School school;
}

class All {
    public List<School> schools;
    public List<Student> students;
}
```

This works exactly as You intended:

```
@Test
public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    var json = "{" +
            "\"schools\":[" +
            "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"School A\"}," +
            "{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"School B\"}" +
            "]," +
            "\"students\":[" +
            "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Bobby\",\"school\":1}" +
            "]" +
            "}";
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var all =  mapper.readValue(json, All.class);
    Assertions.assertThat(all.students.get(0).school).isSameAs(all.schools.get(0));
}
```