# How to link objects use existing id with Jackson annotations?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a data structure (not designed by me, so no chance to change it!). In which one class (e.g. foo) contains other (e.g. bar), and bar contains an array foo. I solved this using `@JsonIdentityInfo` in this manner:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "object.id" )
public class Foo {
   @JsonProperty
   Object id;
   @JsonProperty
   Bar bar;
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "object.id" )
public class Bar{
   @JsonProperty
   Object id;
   @JsonProperty
   List<Foo> foos;
}
```

This deserializes properly but it serializes not completely correct. The issue is this generate an extra id `object.id`. I would like to use the `ID` as the `object.id`. How can I achieve this using Jackson annotations?

I want to parse an serialize this:

Object Foo:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "bar":
      {
        "id":2,
        "foos":[1]
      } 
}
```

and not this:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "object.id":2,
   "bar":
      {
        "id":2,
        "object.id":2,
        "foos":[1]
      } 
}
```

Comment: why has been rated negatively without reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the use of the of `ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class` instead of `ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class` in the annotation configuration `@JsonIdentityInfo`. Addtionally, the scope must be configured as is shown below:

```
 @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Foo.class)
    public class Foo {
       @JsonProperty
       Object id;
       @JsonProperty
       Bar bar;
    }

   @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Bar.class)
    public class Bar{
       @JsonProperty
       Object id;
       @JsonProperty
       List<Foo> foos;
    }
```

I got the answer from [Deserialize with Jackson with reference to an existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081726/deserialize-with-jackson-with-reference-to-an-existing-object)